# Real numbers raised to real powers in differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Find all functions $f: (0, +\infty) \to (0, +\infty)$ that admit as primitive the function $F: (0, +\infty) \to (0, +\infty)$, knowing that $F^\alpha$ is a primitive of $f^\alpha$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \neq 0, \alpha \neq 1$. Here $f^\alpha$ means $f$ raised to the power of $\alpha$, not the composition of the function. 
My approach was the following: $(F^\alpha)'=f^\alpha \implies \alpha * F^{\alpha-1}*f=f^\alpha$. Since $f, F$ are strictly positive, we can divide by $f$, so $\alpha = (\frac{f}{F})^{\alpha-1}$. Now I would raise both sides to the power of $\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$, which implies $ \alpha^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}=\frac{f}{F}$ and solve the separable differential equation, however $\alpha$ may be negative, so there is a problem. I think the problem was not meant for whether or not we can raise negative numbers to real number powers, but I try to be as rigorous as possible. Is there a way we can solve this equation, "avoinding this issue"?

Comment: we have alpha raised to the power of 1/(alpha -1)

Comment: Ah, I see your point clearly now.

Comment: But haven't you argued that $\alpha$ must be positive, since it is a power of $f/F$?